# Having difficult finding the right sized mouse

Tags: mouse

The mouse I'm currently using is a perfect fit for my hand.

I'm trying to find an alternate since it's starting to get old, but I'm having a really hard time finding the same size. I've looked online and been to a few shops but it's difficult to check the mouse in store and see if it's suitable.

I know this sounds like a trivial problem, but without a comfortable grip I get wrist pain after a while.

Can someone give some pointers on how I go about finding another suitable one? The one I'm using now is discontinued. (ADVENT A6BWRD19)

Comment: Note to close-voters. This is not a 'hardware rec', this is a 'how do I go about determining what I need?' rec, which is on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a big retail park with a general electrical/computer shop - Curry's, Best Buy, etc - where they have dozens out on display for you to try.

Having said that - though direct product recommendations are off-topic here - it doesn't look a million miles away from my own Logitech MX Master 2. [Not necessarily to scale, composited from two separate images.]

[image]

Alternatively, check eBay/Amazon etc for remaindered stock of your original.

Comment: Watched a few youtube videos and I managed to fix my current mouse by taking it apart and giving a good clean. Buys me some time and at least I know how to fix it now

Answer (score 0):

I would look for a large electronics store - last time I was in the market for a mouse I went to BestBuy as they had a number of mice unboxed on a table and I could try them out.

In the end BestBuy didn't have the mouse I wanted, but they had a more basic one from the same manufacture and I was able to confirm online that it was the same size as the one I ended up ordering.

Alternatively you could look into cleaning your existing mouse - gaming mice take a lot more abuse - but for work / basic browsing you should be able to keep it for a long time.